# How to convert my code into a different syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a little issue trying to convert the code of another person into a decent code with another kind of convention/syntax

```
function AppController($scope, $window, dataService) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.dateFormat    = 'dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm a';
  vm.appLastUpdate = dataService.lastUpdate;
  vm.sync          = sync;
  vm.online        = navigator.onLine;

  $window.addEventListener('offline', detectConnection, false);
  $window.addEventListener('online', detectConnection, false);

  return vm;

  function sync() {
    vm.idle = true;
    dataService
      .sync()
      .then(function () {
        vm.idle = false;
        vm.showSync = false;
        vm.appLastUpdate = Date.now();
      });
  }

  function detectConnection() {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      vm.online = navigator.online;
    });
  }
}
```

that's what I have so far, but I need it this way

```
.controller('AppController', function($scope, $window, dataService) {...})
```

and I am having some issues with the vm.stuff and all that kind of thing.

So, what should I take into account before translate my code into the another syntax ?

Comment: I think that this kind of syntax in controller is thought to work using controllerAs syntax. Maybe I'm wrong, but you can take a quick look at this page for example: http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/, hope it helps

Comment: @edrian ok but I don't want ```vm``` anymore. What should I do ?

Comment: vm in this example represents $scope, so if you want to try this controller as a regular one (and not using controllerAs), then, you should replace vm with $scope to send updates to the view. Also remove the return vm sentence.

Comment: It's already decent - you need to check out the controllerAs syntax mentioned in the first comment. Don't convert this code, learn from it.

Comment: I think you are using older version of angular..thats why you are able to define controller function as global..you need to do follow modularize approach by creating module..